# Can't open the developer tools (F12) in Internet explorer opened via selenium while debugging

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, debugging, ie-developer-tools

Can't open the developer tools (F12) in Internet explorer opened via selenium while debugging .
I am using

```
<package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />

  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver" version="3.0.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Every time i open the developer tools the application throws 500 . I need to open the developer tools while debugging. 
If i open Internet explorer directly and the application ,no issues in opening the developer tools. but while running through selenium every time i open the application is throwing 500 error.

My application only support IE.
Can some one please help.

Thank you

Comment: While debugging I assume means while the code execution is stopped, like at a breakpoint for example. If that's not what you mean then having the developer tools open will definitely cause problems.

Comment: Exactly . When the code execution is stopped at a break point, and when you want to open the Developer tools . Application throws 500.